# Python - Compare two columns of features, return values which are not common to both

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to compare two columns of features("a", "b") and return only values which are not common to both.  The rows are of unequal size, and values may occur more than once.

I tried:

```
a[np.logical_not(np.in1d(a,b))]
```

But this doesn't seem to work if len(b) > len(a)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC you are looking for a [Symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference):

Source DFs:

```
In [41]: d1
Out[41]:
   a
0  a
1  b
2  c
3  x
4  d
5  l
6  z

In [42]: d2
Out[42]:
   b
0  b
1  a
2  d
3  c
4  y
```

**Numpy solution:**

```
In [43]: np.setdiff1d(np.union1d(d1.a, d2.b), np.intersect1d(d1.a, d2.b))
Out[43]: array(['l', 'x', 'y', 'z'], dtype=object)
```

**Pandas solution:**

```
In [44]: pd.Index.symmetric_difference(pd.Index(d1.a), pd.Index(d2.b))
Out[44]: Index(['l', 'x', 'y', 'z'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Thanks!  Your first explanation indicates the logic perfectly.   Although I don't really understand the symmetric_difference object, it worked in my code (len of columns > 35k).